# Way to enhance SharePoint Designer 2010's text editor?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am forced to work with SP Designer 2010, and realized the built-in text editor it has is terrible. Is there any way to integrate it with VS code or Visual Studio so that I can save files directly in one of those and have the changes appear on my SP site? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind- just realized you can open up your site in VS code and view/edit the files directly.